# Extracting text from a Google document and get particular page

Tags: google-api, html-parsing, google-docs, python-docx, pypdf

As of now, I export my Google documents by getting the content from this link:

`https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Exportid=DOCUMENT_ID&exportFormat=EXPORT_FORMAT`

This works fine, in fact I export my doc to an HTML format then I read from it, but there is no way to know when a page starts or ends.

Here's all the export formats I know of:

HTML, PDF, ODT, TXT, RTF and DOCX

PDF, ODT, RTF and DOCX all indicate separate pages when opened *in a renderer*. However, after searching for countless APIs for all formats (python-docx, PyPDF4, PyRTF etc), I have not been able to find a working way to read a Google document page by page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) with it you can take advantage of the [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app) where you can get [PageBreaks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/page-break).

You could then serve your tailored content as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).